# datanode[slave] running but connect namenode[master]

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos

**i can start hadoop sucess but datanode[slave] can't connect namenode[master]**

```
2016-11-09 16:00:15,953 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: master/192.168.1.101:9000
2016-11-09 16:00:21,957 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.1.101:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-09 16:00:22,965 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/192.168.1.101:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

**detail /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.1.101 master
192.168.1.102 slave1
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**and hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:///opt/volume/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:///opt/volume/datanode</value>
</property>
```

Comment: can you share your /etc/hosts

Comment: ok i can thank for help

Comment: i'm edit now you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check if firewall is restricting port

```
sudo iptables -L
```

if so, flush it

To open 9000,

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

2) check namenode logs for any issues under `/var/log/hadoop`

Comment: `at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:802)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: i should be disabled firewall ?

Comment: maybe firewall is bocking you connectivity to master 9000 port

Comment: how to disabled firewall port 9000 on centos7

Comment: print the output of sudo iptables -L

Comment: now! it's work because i disabled firewall master,slave thank you so much.

Comment: next step. how to install apache hive in apache hadoop cluster